# Get byte address for required bit in flat implementation of bit field?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, offset, bitarray

Given that I allocate memory like this:

```
Create(int width, int height, int depth)
{    
    size_t numBits = width * height * depth;
    size_t numBytes = numBits / 8 + numBits % 8 != 0 ? 1 : 0;
    bytes = malloc(numBytes);
    ...
```

Now I want to get the byte offset for a given x, y, b:

```
DoSomething(int x, int y, int bit)
{
    Byte* byte = bytes + ... some offset ...
```

For example, if I said `Create(3, 3, 3)` and then `DoSomething(0, 1, 1)` I would calculate the byte offset as 0.  If I said `DoSomething(0, 2, 2)` that would be the ninth bit so I would calculate the offset as 1.

Once I have the Byte I can perform the manipulations that I need.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I *think* you got the operator precedence wrong. If you do the calculation of the number of bytes as

```
numBits / 8 + numBits % 8 != 0 ? 1 : 0
```

then it will be parsed as

```
(numBits / 8 + numBits % 8 != 0) ? 1 : 0
```

i. e. you will always end up with 0 or 1 byte being allocated. I think you meant

```
numBits / 8 + (numBits % 8 != 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

instead. Or just do the usual round-up trick:

```
numBytes = (numBits + 7) / 8;
```

Now yes, we can do the maths by hand, but why aren't you simply using a pointer-to-array and leave the hard maths to the compiler?

```
unsigned char (*mat)[height][depth] = malloc((width + 7) / 8 * sizeof(*mat));
```

Then it's trivial to obtain an address:

```
unsigned char *ptr = &mat[x / 8][y][z];
```